# Idk how to fix this bug that I have

Tags: javascript, html, function

It's sad cuz this should be really simple, but for some reason it isn't working.
I am trying to make this be a shortcut for typing in

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML
```

but when I run the program, it doesn't do anything.

Here's my code:

```
function writeTo(text,loc,method){
    var location = document.getElementById(loc);
    if(method == "rep")
        location.innerHTML = text;
    if(method == "add")
        location.innerHTML += text;
    else
        alert("Error: Unknown method \""+method+"\". Use \"rep\" to replace or \"add\" to add.");
}
```

Here's the output area:

```
<p id="test">This is text!</p>
```

and here is what I call:

```
writeTo("Text","test","rep");
```

Comment: Looks fine, but you want the second `if` to be an `else if`. http://jsbin.com/tekaji/1/

Comment: OMG PEOPLE! DONT DOWNVOTE IF YOU CANT ANSWER IT

Comment: I changed it to an else if and it still didn't do anything.

Comment: Compare your code to http://jsbin.com/tekaji/1 Is your call to the `writeTo` function happening before the `test` element is on the page?

Comment: For the JavaScript part there is no difference. This means the only possible problem would be if there is a glitch in the software I am using.

Comment: I think your getting down-voted due to the incredibly lame title you gave your question.  NOT BECAUSE THEY DON'T KNOW THE ANSWER!

Answer (score 0):

I had the JavaScript stored in a separate file so I took the JavaScript and moved it into a

```
<script>
```

tag and it worked. The problem was that the software didn't link the html file to the js file.

Comment: Congratulations, you win!